# NestJs Swagger sends string instead of an array to Api

Tags: api, swagger, nestjs

My Api will sends to server an array of string (list client id)
I'm using @nestjs/swagger version 6.3.0. And I defined the ApiProperty like as below:

`@ApiProperty({ type: "array", items: { type: "string" }, })  clients: string[]`

But, when I test this API from swagger, it sends string instead of array.

[Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40ci3.png)

Please explain this to solve my problem.

I try it but not work.

`@ApiProperty({ isArray: true, items: { type: "string" }, })  clients: string[]`

Thank in advanced.

Comment: A comma-separated list of values is [one of the ways](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query) to send arrays in the query string. In what format does you backend expect the query string? Does it expect something like `?clients=value1&clients=value2&clients=...`? Or `clients[]=...` (with square brackets) instead of `client=...`? Or something else? Once you know which format works, you can update the annotations accordingly.